# Arduino-Makefile: Compiler can't compile the user library cpp files

Tags: c++, c, makefile, arduino

I am trying to use https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile for Arduino on Raspberry Pi with some user cpp libraries but it can not compile and show the error below.

> /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega2560
>   -Wl,--gc-sections -Os -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -o build-mega-atmega2560/toprint.elf build-mega-atmega2560/toprint.ino.o 
>   build-mega-atmega2560/libcore.a -lc -lm 
>   /tmp/cc1J77Gh.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
>   <artificial>:(.text.startup+0x4be): undefined reference to`
>   Str2let::~Str2let()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make:
>   *** [/home/pi/Desktop/demo1_may9/Arduino/toprint/Arduino-Makefile/Arduino.mk:1673:
>   build-mega-atmega2560/toprint.elf] Error 1

My configuration file is as

```
ARDUINO_DIR   = /usr/share/arduino 
MONITOR_PORT  = /dev/ttyACM* 
USER_LIB_PATH = /home/pi/sketchbook/libraries

#BOARD_SUB   = mega2560 #replaced by below 
MCU = atmega2560

# Define Atmega2560 
BOARD_TAG    = mega 
BOARD_SUB    = atmega2560

AVRDUDE      = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr
```

include /home/pi/Desktop/demo1_may9/Arduino/toprint/Arduino-Makefile/Arduino.mk
Does anyone know what happened?

The same code can run on Mac but just not Pi.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by using the `case[2]` in this [post](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/issues/249#issuecomment-54158707). Just don't define the `USER_LIB_PATH` and put all the files in the same location as .ino and Makefile.